# Can't use fontspec with pdflatex

Tags: fontspec, texmaker

I am using tex-maker on manjaro-linux. During compilation I got an error:

```
! Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"!
! The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX.!
! You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or
! "lualatex" instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex".!
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.!
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!............................................... \msg_fatal:nn {fontspec} {cannot-use-pdftex}
```

How to fix it ?

Comment: Don't compile with pdflatex but with xelatex or lualatex.

Comment: How to choose compiler?

Comment: If you are using an editor/IDE then most provide commands for each engine. If you're using the command line, then `xelatex ...` or `lualatex ...` will work. But without more details it's hard to answer this.

Comment: @AlanMunn This must be a duplicate, don't you think?

Answer (score 4):

In the `tools` menu you have `XeLaTeX` submenu, but the simplest is certainly  to go to the `Options -> Configure TeXmaker` menu and either define a shortcut for `XeLaTeX` (there's none by default) or choose `xelatex` as compilation engine for `QuickBuild` (shortcut F1):
[image]